# How use std::thread in C++Builder?

Tags: c++builder, c++builder-10.4-sydney

I wrote a test console application in C++Builder using `std::thread`. The compilation succeeded, but the build failed. Here are the errors:

```
[ilink32 Error] Error: Unresolved external '__Thrd_id' referenced from C:\USERS\D7D1C\DOCUMENTS\C++BUILDER\POLIGON\CONSOLEC++\WIN32\DEBUG\MAIN.OBJ
[ilink32 Error] Error: Unresolved external '__Thrd_join' referenced from C:\USERS\D7D1C\DOCUMENTS\C++BUILDER\POLIGON\CONSOLEC++\WIN32\DEBUG\MAIN.OBJ
[ilink32 Error] Error: Unresolved external 'std::_Throw_Cpp_error(int)' referenced from C:\USERS\D7D1C\DOCUMENTS\C++BUILDER\POLIGON\CONSOLEC++\WIN32\DEBUG\MAIN.OBJ
[ilink32 Error] Error: Unable to perform link
```

Is there a way to compile the program? I know about the `TThread` class, but I wanted to use `std::thread`.

Comment: What steps did you take to create your project in the first place?

Comment: I do again: File - New - Console Application. Then I specify Source type: C++, Target framework: None, set the flag... Multi Threaded. But the first time I did not check this box ... Thank you !!! How to set the Multi Threaded flag in an existing project?

Comment: I don't think there is an option for that after the project is created. You could try diff'ing the 2 projects to see if there is a setting that you can copy over to the old project, or you could just migrate your code to the new project.